# ExtJS 3.2.0, hide tabpanel's header

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabpanel

PLs tell me how i can hide header of tabpanel "..." if my tabpanel have only one tab?

I can't use Ext.Panel becose I use fairly sophisticated methods for generating extjs code on the server, and there is a large number of design errors that do not allow me to generate the usual Ext.Panel for this case.

[image]

tnx all, Solution:
i add to css rules

```
.strip-hidden .x-tab-strip-wrap 
{
    display: none;
} 

.strip-show .x-tab-strip-wrap 
{
     display: block;
}
```

and on server side (delphi, something like ExtPascal)

```
if (frmContainer.Tab.Items.Count = 1) then
     frmContainer.Tab.Cls := 'strip-hidden'
   else
     frmContainer.Tab.Cls := 'strip-show';
```

So, it's work for me (chrome, firefox).

i add 2 rules becose i have windows in windows, so if child windows have many tabs - it will be hidden by css rule of parent window. so i have 2 rules and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to hide the header is to manipulate the CSS. By default, the x-tab-panel-header is applied to the header part of the panel. The following CSS

```
.hideHeader {

    display:none;
}
```

if added to the div would hide the header. To apply the css you need to make use of the `headerCfg` property. Refer the [bodyCfg](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/output/Ext.Panel.html#Ext.Panel-bodyCfg) documentation for details and example of manipulating the default CSS of the panel.

Answer (score 6):

In Version 4.1 you can do the following in the BeforeShow event of the panel/window with the tab control in:

```
Ext.getCmp('tbMyTabPanel').getTabBar().setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that natively.

The container element in this case is already leaving space for the tab, etc. The only thing you could possibly do is add a custom CSS class, and hide the tab completely that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to **hide a tab and its header** in ExtJS 3.x:

```
oTab.hide();
oTab.tabEl.hidden = true;
```

where `oTab` is the your tab component getting from `oTab = oTabPanel.getComponent(x)`;